# How to translate “to parse” or “parsing” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

The act of parsing, in computer science, is the act of taking text (even if it's not human readable) and extract information out of it (and do something with it).

For example you can parse an xml file to gather information about something, Google would parse your webpage to reference it correctly and compiler would parse your code to create an executable representation of a program.

So, how would « parsing » be translated in French?

Wikipedia comes up with *Décomposition analytique*, but I was wondering if there is a better one-word translation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I often use the anglicism "parser" to translate the act of parsing a file.

> The software in charge of parsing the file failed !
>
> Le programme qui devait parser le fichier a planté !

Another possibility is to use "analyser".

> The software in charge of parsing the file failed !
>
> Le programme qui devait analyser le fichier a planté !

It is confirmed by the [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parser).

Comment: On entend aussi fréquemment *Le **parseur** a planté*. Oui, *parser*, *parseur*, et même le vilain *parsage* sont, à tort ou à raison, déjà assez employés (à défaut).

Comment: À tort, à mon avis.
Déjà assez employés, certes mais il faut lutter !

Comment: +1 No proper French for that, use an anglicism. "Decomposition analytique"... Seriously? :)

Answer (score 7):

Like many other words related to IT, *parsing* doesn't have any real translation in french, at least none that I know of.

When speaking, I would use *parsing* or maybe the not-so-nice *parsage*.

In a written document, I would only use *parsing* in that very same typography, i.e. in italics.

As for the verb *to parse*, using *parser* in French sounds and looks quite OK.

Comment: I'd add I sometimes hear (soon : use) « un parse » for the result « du *parsing* » (as a noun).

Answer (score 7):

The [OQLF's Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca) also recommends *analyser*/*analyseur*, but apparently [accepts *parseur*](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8398943) for *parser* (but not *parsage*). Although these terms are recommended for AI and natural language analysis, I think they can be used fine in other areas of informatics.

Answer (score 7):

*Parsing* is *analyse* possibly qualified as *grammaticale*, especially when you want to contrast with *lexing* which would then be *analyse syntaxique*. Obviously *analyseur* (for *parser*) and *analyser* (for *to parse*) are also used.

*Parser* (for *to parse*) and *parseur* (for *parser*) are commonly used in informal contexts, but I don't remember having ever met *parsage* before reading other answers here.

Answer (score 5):

I've mostly heard "parseur" in French. But if I had to translate it, I would say **analyse grammaticale**. In contrast, with "analyse lexicale" for "lexing".

Answer (score 4):

In the context given, parsing has a well established translation: "*analyse syntaxique*".
A parser is an "*analyseur syntaxique*".
"*After parsing*" -> "*après analyse*" ou "*après analyse syntaxique*".

A parser syntactically analyzes an input text, written in a language whose syntax (represented by a grammar) is known by the parser, and builds an internal representation of the text (generally a "parse tree"/"*arbre syntaxique*").

Comment: « *Parse tree* » est selon moi plus habituellement traduit par « arbre de dérivation ».

Comment: Effectivement, dans le domaine, c'est l'expression "analyse syntaxique" qui est généralement utilisée comme équivalent de parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Mieux vaut garder le mot anglais et l'écrire en italique plutôt qu'utiliser un anglicisme, d'ailleurs qualifié par la plupart de « vilain » !

« parser », « parseur » et « parsage » ? À la rigueur à l'oral lors d'une conversation informelle et encore, c'est assez laid. Mieux vaut dire, *parsing*, *parser* et *parsing*.

Une alternative en français serait

> tri syntaxique

avec des variantes possibles en remplaçant le premier mot par `découpage` `analyse`, `décomposition` mais `tri` à l'intérêt d'être court.
Le second mot peut-être remplacé par `grammatical`, quoique l'on puisse utiliser `lexical` pour parler du *lexing* et que donc `syntaxique` fait bien l'affaire.

Comment: "*Mieux vaut*". Pourquoi ? Mieux vaut donner des raisons. Vous avez surement de bonnes raisons - pourquoi pas les partager ?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, I often use "parse", "analyser" or even "convertir".

Answer (score 0):

Parsing =  Analyse grammaticale ou/et analyses syntactique/lexicale. C'est analyser la fonction de chaque mot dans une phrase/clause.

Parse =  Faire de l'analyse grammaticale  etc.

Is this what you needed?

Leda

Answer (score -2):

Parse as computer programming in french, we can say 'formattage d'un texte pour que ce dernier soit lisible ou utilisable par le réceptionneur'. We are not able to translate Parse into a single french word.

Comment: Ce n'est pas ce que veut dire “parse”. “Parse”, c'est passer d'un texte à une représentation interne, pas produire du texte.

Comment: Le but d'un 'parse' en informatique, c'est de découper, nettoyer, formatter, traduire des données reçues afin d'être exploité par le système receveur.